# Words which, cyclically shifted twice, equal their reverse

Tags: formal-languages, context-free, formal-grammars

> Let the alphabet be $Σ = \{0, 1\}$. For any string $w ∈ Σ^*$ of length at least 2, define the
> operation $C_2(w)$ to be a cyclic shift of size 2 on $w$. That is, if $w = w_1w_2 \cdots w_n$ with $n ≥ 2$ and each
> $w_i ∈ Σ$, then $C_2(w) = w_3 \cdots w_nw_1w_2$ if n ≥ 3, and $C_2(w) = w$ if $n = 2$. Recall that $w^R$ means $w$
> written backwards.

> Give a context-free grammar that generates the following language:
> $$ \{w \mid w \text{ has length at least 2 and } C_2(w) = w^R\}. $$

I'm having trouble constructing the context free grammar, so any tips would be much appreciated!

Comment: https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/18524/755

Comment: Please don't [delete your question](https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/136841/755) and then re-post it; we'd prefer that you edit the question instead.

Answer (score 2):

Let us see which words satisfy $C_2(w) = w^R$. Write $w = \sigma \tau x$, where $\sigma,\tau \in \Sigma$ and $x \in \Sigma^*$. Then $C_2(w) = x \sigma \tau$ and $w^R = x^R \tau \sigma$, and so $C_2(w) = w^R$ iff $x = x^R$ and $\sigma = \tau$.

You should be able to use this information in order to construct a grammar for your language.